# Spring + Quartz = Memory Leaks

Tags: spring, quartz-scheduler

I use the following libraries.

- quartz-2.2.1
- spring-webmvc-3.2.9.RELEASE

on Apache Tomcat/7.0.52 (Ubuntu).

I use Spring to configure Quartz.

```
@Configuration
class QuartzConfig {
    @Bean
    FactoryBean<Scheduler> scheduler() {
        final SchedulerFactoryBean factory = new SchedulerFactoryBeanWithShutdownDelay();
        final Map<String, Object> map = new LinkedHashMap<>();
        map.put("settingsService", settingsService);
        final List<AbstractQuartzJob> jobs = new LinkedList<>();
        jobs.add(dbBackupJob());
        jobs.add(csvExportJob());
        jobs.add(csvImportJob());
        jobs.add(dbMaintenanceJob());
        jobs.add(filesystemCleanupJob());
        map.put("jobs", jobs);
        factory.setSchedulerContextAsMap(map);
        factory.setTriggers(new Trigger[] {cronTrigger});
        return factory;
    }
}
```

Searched a lot today why the scheduler tasks where not shut down correctly...

```
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-1] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-2] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-3] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-4] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-5] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-6] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-7] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-8] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-9] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
Jun 24, 2014 5:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/feeder##1.5.0] appears to have started a thread named [scheduler_Worker-10] but has failed to stop it. This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

The ugly hack was to write the SchedulerFactoryBeanWithShutdownDelay class.

```
public class SchedulerFactoryBeanWithShutdownDelay extends SchedulerFactoryBean {
    private static final int SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT = 2000;

    @Override
    public void destroy() throws SchedulerException {
        log.debug("Start shutdown of Quartz scheduler factory bean");
        super.destroy();
        try {
            log.debug("wait {}ms to shutdown Quartz", SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT);
            Thread.sleep(SHUTDOWN_TIMEOUT);
            log.debug("Quartz scheduler shutdown completed");
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            log.error("", e);
        }
    }
}
```

But this issue should have been closed: https://jira.terracotta.org/jira/browse/QTZ-192

Have I made a mistake or can this be confirmed?

Comment: Just out of curiosity, why use quarts when Spring's got its own built-in scheduler?

Comment: Why not? May be it's historically. Used it since we start the project and worked pretty well except of the problems during stop or restart of the web application that was not a problem for us so fare.

Comment: Do you actually have a memory leak or are you just taken away with the messages in your logfile? Also note that spring by default calls `scheduler.shutdown(false)` as the issue mentions `scheduler.shutdown(true)`. To enable the latter set the `waitForJobsToCompleteOnShutdown` property on the `SchedulerFactoryBean` to `true`.

Comment: Yes we actually see memory leaks on our machines. That's why the recommendation to everybody was to restart tomcat after deployment of the Feeder web app. If this was not done often, we see perm gen space errors and need to restart Tomcat then. Thank you for this > `scheduler.shutdown(true)` I have overseen this. Now after changing it, the issues in the log are gone...

Answer (score 2):

An [excellent article](http://blog.bosch-si.com/categories/technology/2011/11/how-to-analyze-leaky-webapps/) on memory leaks in Tomcat. Read the article, start your web app, let Quartz jobs execute, then stop the web app, then take a heap dump of Tomcat's JVM, load the heap dump into Eclipse MAT and find out which classes cause memory leaks. Then you should be able to fix the issue.